# Highlight/bold label on vega chart axis

Tags: vega, vega-lite

Is it possible to highlight certain labels on an axis?

My current encoding is:

```
"encoding": {
       "x": { "field": "date", "type": "temporal", "axis": { "title": "Date", "grid": false } },
       "y": { "field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "axis": { "format": "d" } 
 }
```

And I would like the days of the month (as opposed to the times) to be highlighted/bold so that they easily stand out. Would also like all of these day labels to include the month, rather than the day of the week, so instead of `'Mon 07'` I get want `'Oct 07'` as it is for `'Oct 06'`. Is this possible?

[image: Desired Highlight]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the font style conditioned on the label value, but you can use [axis.labelExpr](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html#example-using-axis-labelexpr-to-display-initial-letters-of-month-name) to change the value of the label depending on a condition.

The [Line Chart With Conditional Axis Properties](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/line_conditional_axis.html) example in the Vega-Lite documentation shows one possible approach that is relevant to your question.

Here is an example of what you might do specifically for multi-day hourly data like yours ([editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEC2CGBOBrSAuKAbAlgOwKaQBpwpdsBjAewBMcBzVMUCCSADwaeZYBcBPAB3xpI3XNH4V4sdIWJdIAM0y50VBm1lcWsVpgDOHOVpGYyiAMIUArtm4MAjACYiW5pHSwARioCCWWtjq6LgKdi6uGF4qAPIKCnq4dmjORvIe3ugAoqz88OoA2tyY0LgAYpJw3AAUVLDcVtAAdABu0la4BGAA5ACkABIoPQCyXQCUnUUl5fCVNXUNLW0d3f1jYAC8690ADNtdYAD8YJNlFXVz9U2t6O2dvZ5gPVRraF1dALqQqWAAvkY-4RYvA4IgEQigAEcrLBbJhuHVMM18J1FMpVOpgX8IADiJAAO6YKjcAAWDAAHLtwpBavDDPJru0DGh8t9gBphI5tpyALTbey8+wAFV2KBFu0IUGBaF5jUcAE4ca42ewOVztgKBcLHKLtjqJZApWAZQBWBWA5jK9Scnl8zXbAAsOr1KMN20aTkVWktqpt-L5woAbE7xS6GDLHPbPVxvVBrerbf7tmTg9t9YaZQBmSPmiAxyBxjX++y6sWp0PSt3G41Ri3s2NqwtCpwptNht1cmu5uv5hsJpuO0uttBugMBzuMbsFvuC+xBwflsD2RrG+zjvNTv1N5PzyUMN1yslrye9zeCzkthftsc5icq+u+zWObU7g17xoZ1c39cn3mOYUlgChzAN17UcI87x7B8uS1C9d2HZdr1ZY8oL-B1YNfNAl22asv2Q+M-VQudAIXJdPyQiCN1-YVt2IuDF0aOUM3Aq0f2g4t0MNRx3TA3CKNYv9mxfQ0l3tMilTwwsBIHWiMLALin2Yn18Ko2cOIYLi5TNciWJQmcaOdOiM2XMSvQkhM-3PISGHtRoO14nTlOgp81MwhieO0pTCwzf8XLk2ycI8+9HO8rlfK4+wtPEvioJC6SDNk+TD3szyExCoj4sNIz7ACqKHK86iwsaJLAsg4KZwAjL1MaUdFKC-LBJkzL3UQ3KUr9bz7DikNDNlYrWrq1KZ3S7rZKM7YWtM6KyvsfSRs46qmOSgb2rPCq5ocZdFpKyjtm85yrNc2datKwt7R8g76PtHLJryhMztCi6TRM6MzL9e6urLOjuSw7NttY+7hs+2TvoY66Xqm06CserjjQAdmOnazvY6HqrB2sIbumdn0asMjIzSKbra3kkY+oDuSM+UJvB263qG3zuS4q6Ef+vT6cZ37+pOzHLJx6Vwo5wnluJs9scqisivczmduNc7eeA99magmWHrln6sWYd5iD+H4gA)):

```
{
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "type": "temporal",
      "field": "x",
      "axis": {
        "tickCount": 12,
        "labelAlign": "left",
        "labelOffset": 2,
        "labelExpr": "[timeFormat(datum.value, '%H:%M'), timeFormat(datum.value, '%H') == '00' ? timeFormat(datum.value, '%b %d') : '']"
      }
    },
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "y"}
  },
  "width": 800,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": "2020-01-01T00:00:00", "y": -0.29},
      {"x": "2020-01-01T02:00:00", "y": -0.59},
      {"x": "2020-01-01T04:00:00", "y": 0.12},
      {"x": "2020-01-01T06:00:00", "y": -0.24},
      {"x": "2020-01-01T08:00:00", "y": -0.34},
      {"x": "2020-01-01T10:00:00", "y": -0.55},
      {"x": "2020-01-01T12:00:00", "y": -0.02},
      {"x": "2020-01-01T14:00:00", "y": 0.66},
      {"x": "2020-01-01T16:00:00", "y": 1.51},
      {"x": "2020-01-01T18:00:00", "y": 0.98},
      {"x": "2020-01-01T20:00:00", "y": 0.06},
      {"x": "2020-01-01T22:00:00", "y": 0.31},
      {"x": "2020-01-02T00:00:00", "y": 0.42},
      {"x": "2020-01-02T02:00:00", "y": 0.56},
      {"x": "2020-01-02T04:00:00", "y": 1.05},
      {"x": "2020-01-02T06:00:00", "y": 1.1},
      {"x": "2020-01-02T08:00:00", "y": 1.93},
      {"x": "2020-01-02T10:00:00", "y": 2.12},
      {"x": "2020-01-02T12:00:00", "y": 1.41},
      {"x": "2020-01-02T14:00:00", "y": 2.22},
      {"x": "2020-01-02T16:00:00", "y": 2.99},
      {"x": "2020-01-02T18:00:00", "y": 3.51},
      {"x": "2020-01-02T20:00:00", "y": 4.02},
      {"x": "2020-01-02T22:00:00", "y": 1.92},
      {"x": "2020-01-03T00:00:00", "y": 2.05},
      {"x": "2020-01-03T02:00:00", "y": 2.19},
      {"x": "2020-01-03T04:00:00", "y": 2.28},
      {"x": "2020-01-03T06:00:00", "y": 3.15},
      {"x": "2020-01-03T08:00:00", "y": 2.8},
      {"x": "2020-01-03T10:00:00", "y": 2.66},
      {"x": "2020-01-03T12:00:00", "y": 3.16},
      {"x": "2020-01-03T14:00:00", "y": 3.28},
      {"x": "2020-01-03T16:00:00", "y": 3.06},
      {"x": "2020-01-03T18:00:00", "y": 2.63},
      {"x": "2020-01-03T20:00:00", "y": 1.53},
      {"x": "2020-01-03T22:00:00", "y": 1.16},
      {"x": "2020-01-04T00:00:00", "y": 1.45},
      {"x": "2020-01-04T02:00:00", "y": -0.51},
      {"x": "2020-01-04T04:00:00", "y": -1.04},
      {"x": "2020-01-04T06:00:00", "y": -1.95},
      {"x": "2020-01-04T08:00:00", "y": -2.57},
      {"x": "2020-01-04T10:00:00", "y": -2.65},
      {"x": "2020-01-04T12:00:00", "y": -3.39},
      {"x": "2020-01-04T14:00:00", "y": -3.296},
      {"x": "2020-01-04T16:00:00", "y": -2.45},
      {"x": "2020-01-04T18:00:00", "y": -2.44},
      {"x": "2020-01-04T20:00:00", "y": -2.14},
      {"x": "2020-01-04T22:00:00", "y": -0.82},
      {"x": "2020-01-05T00:00:00", "y": 0.3},
      {"x": "2020-01-05T02:00:00", "y": 1.04}
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Shame about the formatting but thanks to your suggestion, it is now far more readable so I can live with it. Thanks again, appreciate it.